# $C^1$-functions on Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

For Banach spaces $X,Y$ and an open subset $U$ of $X$  a function $f:U\to Y$ is $C^1$ if $U\to L(X,Y)$, $x\to f'(x)$ is continuous where, by definition, the derivative $f'(x)$ is a continuous linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ satisfying $$\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)(h)\|_Y = o(\|h\|_X)$$ and $L(X,Y)$ is the Banach space of continuous linear operators endowed with the operator norm. Then $f'$ is again a map between Banach spaces and one can define higher derivatives.

For Frechet instead of Banach spaces there are many different topologies on $L(X,Y)$ but none of them is Frechet. To stay in the category one thus needs a different definition. In his exposition of the Nash-Moser theorem
[Hamilton](http://www.ams.org/bull/1982-07-01/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2) therefore tells $f$ continuously differentiable if all directional derivatives $Df(x)(v)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}(f(x+tv)-f(x))/t$ exist in $Y$ and $Df: U\times X \to Y$ is continuous. He then writes:
*Note well that this definition of a $C^1$ map does not agree with the usual
definition for a Banach space. The derivative will of course be the same map (i.e. $Df(x)(v)=f'(x)(v)$),
but our continuity requirement is weaker.*

What is an example (in Banach spaces) showing that the latter definition is *strictly* weaker than the former?

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer so that MO would show no answers to this question.

Comment: It is important to recall that the notion of differentiability employed by Hamilton (called $C^1_c$ in Keller's book mentioned in TaQ's answer below, and also known as *Michal-Bastiani differentiability*) does not come from a locally convex topology in $L(X,Y)$, but rather a so-called *convergence structure* in it (see e.g. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space).

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth: I would like to know what is your motivation for getting a Banach space map showing $C_{\rm c}^{\,1}\not\Rightarrow C_{\rm b}^{\,1}\,$. Since you have indicated that it somehow arises from Hamilton's Nash−Moser article, I wish to point out the following. Hamilton's main goal is to construct the category of tame smooth maps of tame Fréchet spaces, and to get this he uses as "intermediate steps" the finite order continuous differentiabilities $C_{\rm c}^{\,k}$ for $k\in\mathbb N_0\,$. (cont.)

Comment: Since $C_{\rm c}^{\,k+1}\Rightarrow C_{\rm b}^{\,k}$ holds for maps between arbitrary Hausdorff locally convex spaces, see Keller pp. 99−100, it follows that the infinite order differentiabilities $C_{\rm c}^{\,\infty}$ and $C_{\rm b}^{\,\infty}$ *are the same*. If one only considers maps between Fréchet spaces, it even suffices to have $C_{\rm s}^{\,\infty}\,$, which explicitly means that for all fixed $k$ and $u_1,\ldots\,u_k$ the maps $x\mapsto{\rm d}^{\,k}f\,(x)\,\langle\,u_1,\ldots\,u_k\,\rangle$ are continuous. See the figure on page 109 in Keller's book. (cont.)

Comment: So, for Hamilton's purposes, it is quite irrelevant what exactly are the finite order differentiabilities when constructing smoothness.

Comment: In order to avoid unnecessary confusion, I want to add that in my second comment above I intended to say that $C_{\rm c}^{\,\infty}$ and $C_{\rm b}^{\,\infty}$ are equivalent for maps $f:E\supseteq U\to F$ where $E$ and $F$ are arbitrary (real) Hausdorff locally convex spaces such that in addition $E$ is *metrizable*.

Comment: An essential definition, not stated explicitly as such, in Hamilton's paper is on page 143: Suppose now that $F$ and $G$ are graded spaces and $P:U\subseteq F\to G$ is a nonlinear map. We say $P$ is a *smooth tame* map if $P$ is smooth and all its derivatives $D^{\,k}P$ are tame. The category $\mathscr T$ is defined to be that whose objects are tame spaces and whose maps are smooth tame maps. We shall state and prove the Nash-Moser theorem in terms of this category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Banach spaces, continuity of $Df:U\times X \to Y$ and linearity in the second variable implies that $Df: U\to L(X,Y)$ is continuous for the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $X$, and not the operator norm in general.
If $f$ is $C^2_c$ then $Df: U\to L(X,Y)$ is actually continuous into the operator norm.

Since I am travelling, I am now quite incomplete. Sorry.

## EDIT:

I had the opportunity to look up the literature now. An example on $\ell^2$, due to Smolyanov, is in
12.13 of:

- Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor: The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, Volume: 53, American Mathematical Society, Providence, 1997.  [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/apbookh-ams.pdf)

---

Edit by Jochen Wengenroth

The example is the following: Take a smooth function $\varphi$ with support in $[-1/4,1/4]$ and $\varphi(0)=1$. Define $f_k:\ell^2\to \mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto \varphi(k(x_k-1)) \prod\limits_{j<k}\varphi(jx_j)$ and $f=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} f_k$.

Comment: Can you give a more specific reference to a publication of Smolyanov (Smoljanov, O. G.?) for the example in your book? In MathSciNet, I didn't find a clear indication of such a result. (If it appears only in Russian, never mind!)

Answer (score 4):

$\def\kp#1{\kern.#1mm}\def\bbNo{\mathbb N_0}\def\seq#1{\langle\kern.8mm{#1}\kern.6mm\rangle}\def\bbR{\mathbb R}\def\bbZp{\mathbb Z^+}\def\sp#1{\kern.#1mm}$On page 63 in *Differential Calculus in Locally Convex Spaces* H. H. Keller refers to

Y. P. Wong: Differential Calculus and Differentiable Partitions of Unity in Locally Convex Spaces, §1.2, University of Toronto, 1974

for the assertion that $C_{\rm c}^{\kp4 1}$ is strictly weaker than $C_{\rm b}^{\kp4 1}$ for maps between Banach spaces. I have not looked at this paper, and thus I do not know whether one can find there an explicit example or not. I have constructed such an example of a map $c_0(\bbNo)\to c_0(\bbNo)\kp7$, if I recall correctly, but it is unpublished and lies somewhere in my files. The construction and the associated proof are not quite trivial.

**Added.** (14.7.2016) I haven't found my original example but here is a similar one. Let $f:c_0(\bbZp)=E\to E$ be defined by $x\mapsto\seq{n^{-2\,}\varphi\,(\sp3 n^{\,2\,}x_{\kp5 n}):n\in\bbZp}$ where for example $\varphi:\bbR\to\bbR$ is given by $t\mapsto\frac 12\,t\,(\sp4 3 - t^{\,2}\sp2\big)$ for $-1\le t\le 1$ and $t\mapsto{\rm sgn\,}t$ otherwise. It is almost trivial to see that $f$ is continuous. Also the directional derivatives ${\rm D\,}f\,x\,u=\delta\,f\,(\sp3 x\sp3,u\sp3) = \lim_{\,t\,\to\,0\,}t^{-1\,}(\sp3 f\,(\sp3 x + t\,u\sp3) - f\,x\sp3) = \seq{{\rm D\,}\varphi\,(\sp3 n^{\,2\,}x_{\kp5 n}\sp3)\,u_{\kp5 n}:n\in\bbZp}$ are defined for all $x,u$ in $E$. One easily verifies that ${\rm D\,}f\,x$ and $\delta\,f\,(\,\cdot\,,u\sp3)$ are continuous for all fixed $x,u$ in $E\,$. This means that we have $f$ in $C_{\kp3\rm s}^{\,1}$ in Keller's sense, and by Keller's Theorem 1.0.2 (p. 61) we get that also $f$ is $C_{\rm c}^{\,1}\,$, i.e. once continuously differentiable in Hamilton's sense. That $f$ is not $C_{\rm b}^{\,1}\,$, i.e. not once continuously differentiable in the classical Banach space sense, is seen by taking $x = n^{-1\,}{\rm e}_{\kp5 n}$ and $u = {\rm e}_{\kp5 n}$ and letting $n\to +\infty$ since for all $n\in\bbZp$ we then have $((\kp6{\rm D\kp5}f\,x-{\rm D\kp5}f\kp9 0_E\sp3)\,u\sp3)_{\kp5 n} = -\frac 32\,$, if I computed correctly.

One observes that the same example also works for $E=\ell^{\kp9 p\kp5}(\bbZp)$ with $1\le p < +\infty\,$.

**Proof of directional differentiability** (added 15.7.2016)

[image: Proof of directional differentiability]

Comment: Thanks for this "reference" ... The text of Wong, Keller refers to, does not seem to be published, at least I do not find it in the MathReviews or somewhere in the web. I would thus be very interested in your example.

Comment: I accepted Peter Michor's answer although yours was first. However, the other contained a concrete reference. Nevertheless, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different and very natural example from the forthcoming book *Infinite-dimensional Lie Groups. General Theory and Main Examples* by H. Glöckner and K.-H. Neeb. I describe it here with the permission of H. Glöckner.

The function $f:L^1[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]$  is the superposition $\xi\mapsto \sin\circ\xi=\sin(\xi)$. The directional derivatives are $Df(\xi)(\eta)=\cos(\xi)\eta$ -- which looks very plausible but the proof needs some care. On can show that $Df:L^1[0,1] \times L^1[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]$ is continuous but $Df:L^1[0,1] \to \mathcal L_{op}(L^1[0,1])$ is not: Because of $Df(0)=id$ the inverse mapping theorem would imply that the range $f(L^1[0,1])$ contains a $0$-neighbourhood in $L^1[0,1]$ which is not true because this range is contained in the unit ball of $L^\infty[0,1]$ (which is of first category). If one prefers a Hilbert space example one can replace $L^1$ by $L^2$.